# Solve Exception handling

Tags: java

Why we use exception subclasses? if we can handle the exception only exception class, like:

```
try { 
}
catch(Exception e) { 
}
```

then why we use subclasses like `ArithmeticException`,`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Because you may want to handle ArithmeticExceptions differently than ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ??

Comment: Because you might want to have different exception handling for different exceptions that are thrown, like ignoring one, or set a number to a default value after a formatexception is thrown

Comment: Because you don't want to tell the user that the file doesn't exist, whenever your program has a bug.

Comment: Wow, this question attracted lots of answers O.o

Comment: Catching "Exception" catches "RuntimeException" too.

Comment: @immibis: no, it didn't. It only attracted one answer, but it was given by several people.

Comment: @Stultuske ... on Stack Overflow, "answer" is a type of object which is created by pressing the Post Answer button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception classification help use understand what exactly is the issue at hand easily even before we see the description. It is a first sigth informer to the developer to understand the issue. For example if you are getting a NullPointerException / ArithemeticException and if you just say "Exception occured" can we understand anything? without a detailed explanation. So its a means to categorize the error but ofcourse a more details explanation is given by the error description by developer who has coded.

Answer (score 2):

Because catching `Exception` is very general, how will you know if it's `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NullPointerException`? What if you want to handle each one differently?

Example:

```
try {
   veryComplicatedLogic();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // null pointer? out of bounds? custom exception?
}
```

It's very bad practice to catch an `Exception`, try to keep your scope as small as possible and be specific as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you catch `Exception` you get every failure<sup>1</sup> ... and there is no way that you can write code that will recover (properly) in the event of all possible failures.

Hint: many of those possible exceptions could be the result of a programming error (a bug!) that cannot be recovered from safely.

---

<sup>1 - Not strictly true.  To catch *everything* you would need to catch `Throwable`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

it is useful to categorize different types of errors, and more importantly the rectifying steps

for example

```
    try
    {
        //read a file
        //write to a database
    }catch(IOException e1)
    {
        // catch block to do something about the file io error
        // and provide appropriate error message

    }catch(SQLException e2)
    {
        // catch block to do something about the SQL error
        // and provide appropriate error message

    }catch(Exception e3)
    {
        // catch block for any other exceptions, perhaps runtime exceptions
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions are derived from class `Exception`. We can have a sequence of `catches` for all possible `expected` exceptions like `ArithmeticException`,`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

At last we can have a catch with argument of type `Exception`. When one of the above `expected`  expections arise they will be caught by one of the corresponding catches. Others will be caught by last `Exception`(base class)

Note: Base class exception can catch all its derived class exceptions. So there will be no use when you have

```
 catch(Exception) { . . .}
```

in front of

```
  catch(someExp){. . . }
```

whew `someExp` can be any exception like `ArithmeticException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or any other `user define ones`.

**EDIT** We can get specific exception details and handle it accordingly when we know the `specific` exception. That is the use of deriving other exceptions

Comment: You are answering how multiple catch blocks work, but I think the asker wants to know why it's useful to have any exception classes besides `Exception` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch, let's say, an`ArithmeticException` before the class `Exception`, it'll first try to catch that specific ArithmeticException. If a `NullPointerException` is caught instead, it'll skip the first catch and go to the 2nd. Like this:

```
try {
    //Code here
} catch(ArithmeticException ame) {
    //Do something to catch the ArithmeticException
} catch(Exception e) {
    //Catch all remaining Exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` is superclass of all exceptions So if you catch exception using it so their will be problem occurred at programmer side like if some other programmer wants to read the program so it takes time to find which exception is going to be handle.
`In short it is poor design.`

Answer (score 0):

I present the difference between the common (i.e. using only Exception class) and the sophisticated (i.e. using Exception's subclasses) exception handling with an example.

You have to implement a method which receives two positive integer numbers in character string format as arguments, divides the first with the second and returns the integer part of this division.

There are two main possible error sources: bad number format in strings, division with 0. Certainly the method has to handle these errors and indicate it to the caller method.

If you are not interested why an error occurs the best way is to handle the Exception object:

```
int stringDiv(String str1, String str2)
{
    try
    {
        int i1 = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(str1));
        int i2 = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(str2));

        return i1 / i2;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

...

System.out.println(stringDiv("114", "11"));  //Output: 10 
System.out.println(stringDiv("a114", "11")); //Output: -1
System.out.println(stringDiv("114", "0"));   //Output: -1
```

But if you want to indicate to the caller method what was the problem with the inputs you have to handle all the exception types separatelly:

```
static int stringDiv2(String str1, String str2)
{
    try
    {
        int i1 = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(str1));
        int i2 = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(str2));

        return i1 / i2;

    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return -100;
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException ex)
    {
        return -200;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return -300;
    }
}

...

System.out.println(stringDiv2("114", "11"));  //Output: 10 
System.out.println(stringDiv2("a114", "11")); //Output: -100
System.out.println(stringDiv2("114", "0"));   //Output: -200
```